# What brand and style is this D20?

Tags: dice, product-identification

I've had this one die for nearly 30 years, and I just started sorting and displaying my collection so I'm trying to find out which brand/style it is so I can hopefully complete the set someday.  I thought it might have been the Chessex run of speckled dice, but the colors don't match anything else. The closest I've come to a match has either pink, blue, or green numbering, but mine is white.

Does anyone know? Searches for "red blue speckled dice" turn up bupkus. (I've now searched eBay, most well-known dice seller shops online, and the dice collector's page with reference photos, all turning up nothing.)

I thought it might be one of the Veronica Chessex dice, but the speckling seems broader than the Chessex varieties. Also, the font and the white numbering likely means it's not one of those either.  It's also not from a card or board game, to my knowledge. I'm pretty sure I picked it up as a single at an old RPG shop back in the day.

Per the comments: Yes, the 1 is opposite the 20.  There are no symbols, only numbers.  I've added an image of the 20 face as well.

[image: Mystery Die]

[image: Mystery Die 2]

Comment: Does it have any symbols on the 1 or 20?

Comment: When you look at the 20 face, what are the numbers immediately adjacent to it? Also is the number on the opposite side of the 20 a 1?

Comment: Maybe [this guy selling one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Old-D20-16mm-Twenty-Sided-Die-Speckled-Red-Blue-with-Green-/223459283850) remembers? :)

Comment: That one being sold is not what I described, though. It doesn't have white numbers, and the speckling is tighter, with less bleed-out like this one. It is similar, but not from the same series.

Comment: I got a very similar one bundled together with my very first AD&D book. Did yours come by any chance bundled with something else?

Comment: That is possible. I did buy the AD&D 2nd edition box sets... On the other hand I've searched for those and they all seem to be solid color dice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's an old Torg die that came in the Torg starter set back in the day. You won't find a full polyhedral set though.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it could be it. The font is still different here (http://roguesgallerytx.com/games/torg-eternity-rpg-dice-pack/) but that could just be the reproduction, I'm guessing.

Comment: Yup. That red-blue mixture was a theme of TORG, and part of an important set of scenarios.

Comment: Found the old one here, thanks to GunsNAmmo, (http://bigballofnofun.blogspot.com/2013/09/30-day-d-your-favorite-set-of-dice.html). Definitely the one! Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. The answer would be improved by including evidence (such as the link in the second comment) that shows that its claim is correct.